# Metadata and multiple - interleaved, insertable - streams: which file format?

Tags: sqlite, format, metadata, stream

Once I think about new software projects and current-age data uses, I cannot stand raw files anymore. they seem unnatural now.

Basically a file should contain one or more data "streams", metadata/attributes, etc.

The file should be optimized for sequential, parallel read (like mkv I think) but have reasonable performance for direct ("random") read access, possiby write access, and direct insertions.

Maybe even explicit logical data structure (inside each stream) might be useful.

mkv seems a pretty generic container format, but it seems to not completely fit the need and iirc has some multimedia-specific features in the container format itself

I see sqlite suggested as an alternative, but has an all-file locking mechanism and I just don't know how stream data gets organized (if it stays multimedia-friendly enough or if it's more single-access optimized)

Do you have any hint for me? Are there any other open, cross-platform, generic container, generic-access optimized, insertable data formats? What could I study?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about HDF5?

Comment: absolutely never heard of it!! seems very interesting, will look into it; thank you a lot